# In OCaml, what does aliasing a module do exactly?

Tags: module, ocaml

In OCaml, to bring another module in scope you can use `open`. But what about code like this:

```ml
module A = struct
  include B.C

  module D = B.E
end
```

Does this create an entirely new module called `A` that has nothing to do with the modules created by `B`? Or are the types in `B` equivalent to this new structure and can a type in `A.t` can be used interchangeably with a type in `B.C.t` for example?

Especially, comparing to Rust I believe this is very different from writing something like

```rust
pub mod a {
  pub use b::c::*;
  pub use b::e as d;
}
```

Comment: A pretty good source of information on "what does X do" in a language is the language manual. The OCaml manual has [a whole section on module aliases](https://ocaml.org/manual/modulealias.html).

Comment: I tried reading that page first, but there's honestly too much jargon

Comment: It is worthwhile to notice that there are no module aliases in this question. Module aliases is the notion of signature, not module definitions. So this page is pretty irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `module A = struct include B.C end` creates an entirely new module and exports all definitions from `B.C`. All abstract types and data types that are imported from `B.C` are explicitly related to that module.

In other words, suppose you have

```
module Inner = struct
  type imp = Foo
  type t = int
end
```

so when we import `Inner` we can access the `Inner` definitions,

```
module A = struct
  include Inner
  let x : imp = Foo
  let 1 : t = 1
end
```

and the `Foo` constructor in `A` belongs to the same type as the `Foo` constructor in the `Inner` module so that the following typechecks,

```
A.x = Inner.Foo
```

In other words, `include` is not a mere copy-paste, but something like this,

```
module A = struct 
  (* include Inner expands to *)
  type imp = Inner.imp = Foo
  type t = Inner.t = int
end
```

This operation of preserving type equalities is formally called *strengthening* and *always* applied when OCaml infers module type. In other words, the type system never forgets the type sharing constraints and the only way to remove them is to explicitly specify the module type that doesn't expose the sharing constraints (or use the `module type of` construct, see below).

For example, if we will define a module type

```
module type S = sig 
  type imp = Foo
  type t = int
end
```

then

```
module A = struct 
  include (Inner : S)
end
```

will generate a new type `foo`, so `A.Foo = Inner.Foo` will no longer type check. The same could be achieved with the `module type of` construct that explicitly disables module type strengthening,

```
module A = struct
  include (Inner : module type of Inner)
end
```

will again produce `A.Foo` that is distinct from `Inner.Foo`. Note that `type  t` will be still compatible in all implementation as it is a *manifest type* and `A.t` is equal to `Inner.t` not via a sharing constraint but since both are equal to `int`.

Now, you might probably have the question, what is the difference between,

```
module A = Inner
```

and

```
module A = struct include Inner end
```

The answer is simple. Semantically they are equivalent. Moreover, the former *is not a module alias* as you might think. Both are *module definitions*. And both will define a new module `A` with exactly the same module type.

A module alias is a feature that exists on the (module) type level, i.e., in the signatures, e.g.,

```
module Main : sig 
  module A = Inner (* now this is the module alias *)
end = struct 
  module A = Inner
end
```

So what the module alias is saying, on the module level, is that `A` is not only has the same type as `Inner` but it is exactly the `Inner` module. Which opens to the compiler and toolchain a few opportunities. For example, the compiler may eschew module copying as well as enable module packing.

But all this has nothing to do with the observed semantics and especially with the typing. If we will forget about the explicit equality (that is again used mostly for more optimal module packing, e.g., in dune) then the following definition of the module `A`

```
module Main = struct 
  module A = Inner
end
```

is exactly the same as the above that was using the module aliasing. Anything that was typed with the previous definition will be typed with the new definition (modulo module type aliases). It is as strong. And the following is as strong,

```
module Main = struct 
  module A = struct include Inner end
end
```

and even the following,

```
module Main : sig 
 module A : sig 
   type imp = Impl.imp = Foo
   type t = Impl.t = int
 end
end = struct 
  module A = Impl
end
```

Comment: `struct module X = Y end` really is a module alias currently, and this is observable with applicative functors. Depending on your implementation, `Set.Make(Main.A).t` might or might be not the same type as `Set.Make(Inner).t`.

Comment: There's no such thing as a module alias on the module structure level. In the official documentation, there are only module aliases that were introduced on the signature level. The fact that a module definition with the module path on the right-hand side has any special representation is a detail of implementation.

Comment: This is sophistry since only definitions of the form `struct module A = Path end` have type `sig module A = Path end`. The definition `module Main = struct module A = struct include Inner end` does not have the type `module Main: sig module A = Inner end` contrarily to what the last part of your answer is hinting at.

Comment: That's why  I am saying "modulo type aliases", if we exclude module type aliases (the only typing rule that requires that the module is defined via an explicit path) the rest of the typing rules are applicable. And again, unless we explicitly introduce module aliases on the structure level in the documentation, we can't say that such a thing exists. Right now, as of OCaml 4.13 there are no module aliases on the structure level. Do we want to introduce it, is a separate question. The OP as well as most of the OCaml users and interested in type sharing and if the values and constructors match.

Comment: “When we import Foo”, you mean “when we open A”?

Comment: No, I mean when we `include A`. Here when I say "importing" I am referring to the specific meaning that I introduced in the beginning of the answer, where I said that `include B.C` imports all definitions from `B.C`